# Use one AWS Elastic IP for several instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I need to provide my customers with fixed urls that don't change when the EC2 instances are stopped/started because sometimes we need to change the size of the EC2 and when we restart the instance the public IP has changed.

I thought on using Elastic IPs so I can keep the same public IP when the instance is rebooted, but I've seen that Amazon tells you that you only have 5 Elastic IPs. If you ask them they say that they can give you more, but I guess they're not giving you 10.000 of them.

How can I use a single public Elastic IP to give each user different URLs for out service?

It would be something like this, being `11.22.33.44` the Elastic IP and `192.168.0.X two EC2 instances`:

```
11.22.33.44:**1000** --> 192.168.0.**1**:22
11.22.33.44:**1001** --> 192.168.0.**1**:80
11.22.33.44:**1002** --> 192.168.0.**1**:443

11.22.33.44:**1003** --> 192.168.0.**2**:22
11.22.33.44:**1004** --> 192.168.0.**2**:80
11.22.33.44:**1005** --> 192.168.0.**2**:443
```

I need to make it work programmatically, as I'm creating EC2 instances from the SDK as needed.

Another way I thought is using subdomains from my .com domain that points to the current public IP of each EC2 instance, but using the IP as I described before sounds better.

Comment: They'll give you 10,000 elastic IPs if you have a legitimate need for them, but this isn't really one of those scenarios. You need a load balancer (ELB) and some DNS records like `client1.example.com`, `client2.example.com`, etc. pointed at it.

Comment: The DNS solution is the only way this is going to work. You won't be able to get that many static IP addresses, and DNS is also more future proof if you want to place load balancers or API Gateway or a CDN or something in front of those instances later.

Comment: @ceejayoz What is the load balancer used for? If I already point each DNS record to a public IP, I don't need more, right?

Comment: @LuisMiguelGarcíaMancebo One IP for several instances means a load balancer. If you only want a single instance to be associated with each DNS record, you can forgo the LB.

Comment: Side-comment: Providing a separate Amazon EC2 instance for each customer is good for separation, but not good for scaling and cost efficiencies. It might be worthwhile investigating how you can implement **multi-tenancy** so that EC2 capacity can be shared across multiple customers. It will also greatly reduce your costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that instances are receiving new (temporary) Public IP addresses after they are stopped and started.

A simple way to handle this is to **add a script to each instance that runs during every boot**. This script can **update a DNS record** to point it at the instance.

The script should go into the `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot` directory, which will cause Cloud-Init to automatically run the script each time the instance is started.

```sh
# Set these values based on your Route 53 Record Sets
ZONE_ID=Z3NAOAOAABC1XY
RECORD_SET=my-domain.com

# Extract information about the Instance
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/)
AZ=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/)
MY_IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/)

# Extract Name tag associated with instance
NAME_TAG=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region ${AZ::-1} --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=${INSTANCE_ID}" --query 'Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' --output text)

# Update Route 53 Record Set based on the Name tag to the current Public IP address of the Instance
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $ZONE_ID --change-batch '{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"'$NAME_TAG.$RECORD_SET'","Type":"A","TTL":300,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"'$MY_IP'"}]}}]}'
```

The script will extract the `Name` tag of the instance and update the corresponding Record Set in Route 53. (Feel free to change this to use a different Tag.) The instance will also require IAM permissions for `ec2 describe-tags` and `route53 change-resource-record-sets`.

**Update:** I've turned this answer into a blog post: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)

Comment: Thanks @John, that seems like a good way to do it.

As I'm creating the instances myself, I can know the IP and update it in Route 53, but I  have to think if it's better that the instance do it itself like you proposed.

Comment: Yes, you can do it when creating the instance, but the above method also updates the DNS Name to the new public IP address if an instance is stopped and started.