# change record set with aws cli fails

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I have the following bash script, which updates the DNS record:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Update the DNS for Production DB

RECORD=$1
if [ -z "${RECORD}" ]; then
    echo "Please provide a valid record (URL endpoint) to the database"
    exit 1
fi

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZPXXX --cli-input-json "{\"HostedZoneId\":\"Z1R8UBAEXAMPLE\",\"ChangeBatch\":{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\":{\"Name\":\"catalogue-write-database-prod..domain.tld.\",\"Type\":\"CNAME\",\"TTL\":300,\"ResourceRecords\":[{\"Value\":\"${RECORD}\"}]}}]}}"
ID=$(aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZPXXX --cli-input-json "{\"HostedZoneId\":\"Z1R8UBAEXAMPLE\",\"ChangeBatch\":{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\":{\"Name\":\"catalogue-read-database-prod.domain.tld.\",\"Type\":\"CNAME\",\"TTL\":300,\"ResourceRecords\":[{\"Value\":\"${RECORD}\"}]}}]}}"   | grep "/change/" | cut -c 15- | sed -e 's/"//g')
echo "Change ID: ${ID}"
aws route53 get-change --id ${ID} | grep INSYNC
while [ $? -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "WAITING FOR DNS TO UPDATE... PLEASE WAIT"
    sleep 5s
    aws route53 get-change --id ${ID} | grep INSYNC
done
```

But I get:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchChange) when calling the GetChange operation: Could not find resource with ID: CG1AG9APE0Q8J,
```

my aws version is:

```
+ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.291 Python/3.4.2 Linux/3.16.0-25-generic botocore/1.13.27
```

where as on on this version, the scripts runs correctly

```
+ aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.15 Python/2.7.8 Linux/3.16.0-25-generic botocore/1.3.15
```

Any advise is much appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is the trailing comma in `CG1AG9APE0Q8J,` . Consider using a JSON parsing tool to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: @thatotherguy You don't need a separate json parsing tool with awscli. It natively supports json parsing via jmespath with the `--filter` option.

Comment: Here's a similar script: [Use one AWS Elastic IP for several instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977634/174777)

Comment: check your regions/zones, and explicitly set them - usually when I get could not find resource ID errors its because the default locations are being used and don't match where the resource is located.